# Подключение Jquery через npm к js

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm

```
Ставлю jQuery через npm.Получаю такие вот ошибки. Подскажите, как исправить, сам не разберусь т.к начинающий.В целом, я понимаю, проблема с прокси?
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Полный лог ошибки:
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   'jquery'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.5.5
2 info using node@v16.15.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\html\js\JScommon\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 4ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Сергей\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 13ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 13ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
22 timing npm:load:display Completed in 3ms
23 verbose logfile C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-11T11_56_23_536Z-debug-0.log
24 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 8ms
25 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
27 timing npm:load Completed in 26ms
28 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
29 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 3 files
30 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
31 timing idealTree:init Completed in 11ms
32 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
33 silly idealTree buildDeps
34 silly fetch manifest jquery@*
35 silly placeDep ROOT jquery@ OK for: qw@1.0.0 want: *
36 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 133171ms
37 timing idealTree:node_modules/jquery Completed in 0ms
38 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 133172ms
39 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 0ms
40 timing idealTree Completed in 133186ms
41 timing command:install Completed in 133196ms
42 verbose type system
43 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:443
43 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
43 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
43 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
43 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:539:35)
43 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
43 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
43 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
44 verbose cwd C:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\html\js\JScommon
45 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
46 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "jquery"
47 verbose node v16.15.0
48 verbose npm  v8.5.5
49 error code ETIMEDOUT
50 error syscall connect
51 error errno ETIMEDOUT
52 error network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:443
53 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
53 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
53 error network
53 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
53 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
54 verbose exit 1
55 timing npm Completed in 133538ms
56 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1652270183871
57 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1652270183879
58 verbose code 1
59 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
59 error     C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-11T11_56_23_536Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

и потом

```
npm i jquery
```

---

Второй вариант

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm i jquery
```

Comment: не помогло, тоже самое

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте второй вариант

Answer (score 0):

выводит те же ошибки. Я не уточнил, изучаю js на основной работе, не связанной с программированием. Здесь есть админ со своим сервером, и в инет я выхожу через него. Возможно ошибка подключения к репозитории npm связана с этим, и есть ли возможность это обойти?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).